# How to use the same Azure SQL VM in two different Load Balancers

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener, azure-vm, load-balancing

I have already configured always on availability group between VM1 and VM2 azure machines. Internal Load Balancer was created for these two VMs and mapped to AG Listener. VM2 is used for read workload with the help of read-only routing feature of SQL Server.

Now I provisioned a new VM3 for different application databases and created an availability group between VM2 and VM3. I am planning to use the same VM2 for read workload purposes like I did for VM1 & VM2 pair. Unfortunately I cannot add VM2 into different Internal Load Balancer in order to map to a different AG listener as it is already exists in previously created ILB.

I could not find any articles/blogs who faced with this kind of scenario. Does someone have experience with that or have ideas?

Comment: It's Azure; so you either need a load balancer or to have each VM in a different subnet.